# why images dont show in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

i pass an image address to a component , But it doesnt show that !!
i also use require() But nothing .
this is component code

```
   <div  >
      <img :src="require(data.src)" class="ccard-right-img" alt="" />
    </div>
```

and this is paent component code :

```
<product-card
:data="{cat: 'category', title: 'card title', src: '~/static/1.png' }"
/>
```

how can i fix it ??

Answer (score 1):

finally i didi it like this:

```
<img :src="require('@/static/'+data.src+'.png')" class="ccard-right-img" alt="" />
```